# Xcode 4 - failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I've seen several posts on this error, I've read all of them but with no success , I will be glad for a solution. Here is the output I recieve when compiling ...

```
ld: duplicate symbol _pointOffsetArray in /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Display_Cubes_2-acsuoldwvhwsnjfowhhxfsmdeekc/Build/Intermediates/Display Cubes 2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Display Cubes 2.build/Objects-normal/i386/Display_Cubes_2ViewController.o and /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Display_Cubes_2-acsuoldwvhwsnjfowhhxfsmdeekc/Build/Intermediates/Display Cubes 2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Display Cubes 2.build/Objects-normal/i386/Display_Cubes_2AppDelegate.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have a symbol called pointOffsetArray (or something to that effect?) Can you provide the code for the declaration/definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is that you probably have a global symbol called _pointerOffsetArray (or something similar) [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable#Definition.2C_declaration_and_the_extern_keyword) in two different files. Look for all instances where this symbol is globally defined, and if you do find two different declarations:

1. If they are needed only in their respective files, qualify them with `static` keyword.
2. If the symbol needs to be "shared" between the two files, then make sure that it is defined at only one place. You can refer to it in the other file by using the `extern` qualifier to declare it (in this other file).

If you don't know already, you really should read up on how the `extern` and `static` qualifiers work.

In your case the symbol is probably defined twice in `Display_Cubes_2ViewController.m` or `Display_Cubes_2AppDelegate.m` (or, most likely, you are importing a header file in both of these files which defines this symbol).

Comment: resolved, thanks ... exactly what you described ... :) _pointerOffsetArray wasn't declared (at least i didn't find it) but i have been importing a header file in both files

Comment: You mean the symbol `pointerOffsetArray` is **defined** in two different files, not *declared*.  `extern int pointerOffsetArray;` is a declaration, while `int pointerOffsetArray;` (at global scope) is a definition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the duplicate symbols are in `Display_Cubes_2ViewController` and `Display_Cubes_2AppDelegate`. Try renaming them.

Additionally, you might want to try cleaning your build folder with

> Command + Option + Shift + K

Although this may seem like a blanket solution, it's helped me solve some stupid compile issues in the past. Good luck!